# Move all the contents of a folder with a .bat

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I using the following syntax to move all the files inside a folder, to another folder

```
set OGGI=%DATE:~6,4%-%DATE:~3,2%-%DATE:~0,2%
move C:\DOCUMENTALE\dms_in\*.* C:\DOCUMENTALE\dms_backup\%OGGI%\
```

This syntax is working with files, but which syntax I have to use if I would move also folders?
The problem is that this path C:\DOCUMENTALE\dms_in\ contains folders automatically generated. I don't know how many folders there are in or which names they have.
I did some attempt but I didn't figure it out

Thanks

Comment: `move C:\DOCUMENTALE\dms_in C:\DOCUMENTALE\dms_backup\%OGGI%\` is the easiest. Else move each file. Then do a `for /d` loop to move folders.

Comment: `robocopy` has a `/mov` switch.

Comment: robocopy has a nice mirroring feature as well (/MIR).

Comment: @Stephan can I have an example of how to use it? The goal is to move the content of C:\DOCUMENTALE\dms_in (folders and files) without moving C:\DOCUMENTALE\dms_in itself, thanks

Comment: @jwdonahue can I have an example of how to use it? The goal is to move the content of C:\DOCUMENTALE\dms_in (folders and files) without moving C:\DOCUMENTALE\dms_in itself, thanks

Comment: @GiuseppeCav `robocopy /?` for help.  Simple: `robocpy source dest /MIR`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An solution to this is to use the command ROBOCOPY instead. It is arguable more flexible.

```
ROBOCOPY <source> <destination> /MOV /E
```

/MOV will move the file/folder in question instead of the default copy.

/E will allow you to mirror the directory structure of the target folder if there are any folders within the folder including empty ones

*Note*: you may need to use quotation marks for the source and destination if either path contains spaces.

Another neat feature of Robocopy is that it will show you what is it doing; what is being copied and too where, how long it takes etc. And if it goes wrong due to paths for example, it will tell you.

You can also browse ss64.com for more help and examples to fit your needs.